# How to match following regex?

Tags: regex

I have the following oneliner:

```
Download of file /xxx/xxx-xxx/Xxx/Xx_XX/xxx/xxx xxx/Xxxx/xxxx/xxxx.png to /home/ec2-user/xxx/xx/xx/Xxxy/xx_XX_XX/xxx/xxx xxx/XXX/xxxx/Xxx.png failed
```

How can I match the first `/xxx/xxx-xxx/Xxx/Xx_XX/xxx/xxx xxx/Xxxx/xxxx/xxxx.png`?
It will always start with "`/`" and always end with `.png`. The rest in between can me chars, capitals, numbers, spaces, _ and - (everything). How can I match this regex?

Comment: The constraints are unclear. Do you know exactly how many directories there are in your tree? Are you searching for all PNG files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?<=file ).*(?= to)
```

yields the wished result. [Online](https://regex101.com/r/vJc1j0/1)

Answer (score 0):

N oneed for lookarounds, use:

```
/.*?\.png
```

It finds the match in 55 steps, the other answer matches in 217 steps.

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/hdnTIw/1)